# compare three different values and return true false accordingly?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a below code which takes three input parameters a, b and c and compare three different values and basis on that it returns true false..

```
public boolean compare(int a, int b, int c) {
    int value = increment(a, c);
    if (a < value && b < c || a < value && b > c && c < b) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private int increment(int a, int c) {
    int f = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        f += a;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Any better way to write this?

Comment: "and basis on that" doesn't tell us anything.  We can't read your mind.  When do you want the result to be true, and when do you want it to be false.

Comment: You should put in parenthesis to clarify the groupings of `&&`s and `||`s, readers shouldn't have to look up boolean operator precedence to find out what your code is doing

Comment: @River he can put in all the parentheses he likes, it's still not going to help us figure out what his code is doing

Comment: Isn't `b > c && c < b` rather *redundant*? If `b` is greater than `c`, then `c` is definitely less than `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an undefined method `u` in your code.  Assuming `u` is a misspelling of `increment`, then this is the simplest you can get:

```
public boolean compare(int a, int b, int c) {
    return c > 1 && b != c;
}
```

Your `increment` function returns the product of the two numbers (which means it has the wrong name).  If `value` is `increment(a, c)`, then `value` is `a * c`.  If you compare `a < a * c` and are given that `a` and `c` are greater than 0, then since `a*c` equals `a` if `c==1` and is greater than `a` if `c>1`, then `a < a * c` is equivalent to testing whether `c > 1`.

Looking at your condition, `((a < value && b < c) || (a < value && b > c && c < b))`:  This returns true if either of the expressions around `||` is true.  But `a < value` has to be true in both cases.  So we can extract it.  So for the expression to be true, `a < value` has to be true, and then either of the remaining parts of the expressions has to be true, so the above is equivalent to

```
a < value && (b < c || (b > c && c < b))
```

and since `b > c` means the same thing as `c < b` we can eliminate the redundancy:

```
a < value && (b < c || b > c)
```

and testing whether `b` is either less than or greater than `c` is the same as testing that they're not equal:

```
a < value && b != c
```

and as was shown above, `a < value` is the same as `c > 1`, thus

```
c > 1 && b != c
```

Comment: Wow, `u` *was* a misspelling of `increment`... I thought that was a bit of a stretch for an assumption. SO continues to impress. Nice simplification of it all down after getting past that

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i can reduce is your `increment()`, it can be a single line expression. Also use parenthesis in `if` condition to make it more clear. Also `b>c && c<b` is same thing in two form reduce it to `b>c` only.

```
public boolean compare(int a, int b, int c) {
    int value = a*c;
    if (a < value && b < c || a < value && b > c) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can clarify what you want to do here, the code as you have laid it out is very repetitive and looks like it might have logic bugs...

As for simplification:

**1) The `if` in `compare` can be greatly simplified:**

```
if (a < value && b!=c) {
    return true;
}
```

This is because  you test for `a < value` on both sides of the `||`, and then test for `b<c` on one side and `c<b` on the other. Thus this only fails when `a>value` or when `b==c`.

**2) In `increment` you can just multiply your input parameters:**

```
private int increment(int a, int c) {
    return a*c;
}
```

You add `a` a number of times equal to `c`, which is exactly what multiplication does...